# Fortran arrays seems to be accessed outside of WHERE conditions in the case of debug compilation

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

I'm considering a quite complex fortran code with many interconnected modules, etc .. So I'll do my best to document only a very specific part of it.

The code goes fine when compiled in 'normal' conditions (cf. detail below), but the following lines cause an error (SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation) when using DEBUG compiling options (ironic, isn't?)

```
WHERE (maskatc_int)
   temp_factor = Tfamp*EXP(Tfexp*temp(1:ncloc,1:nrloc,k))
ELSEWHERE
   temp_factor = 0.0
END WHERE
```

this occurs in a function, where `temp_factor` is declared locally

```
REAL, DIMENSION(ncloc,nrloc) :: temp_factor
```

`temp` is declared and allocated in another module, as

```
ALLOCATE (temp(1-nhalo:ncloc+nhalo,1-nhalo:nrloc+nhalo,nz),STAT=errstat)
```

`maskatc_int` has the good dimensions.

```
ALLOCATE (maskatc_int(ncloc,nrloc),STAT=errstat)
```

I can provide much further details if it helps, but I'll stick to those for now, in the hope someone can already provide track of solution (so, avoid the error when compiling and executing in DEBUG mode)

Compilation flags :

'normal' :

```
# Linux grid0 (GNU Fortran with MPI)
linux-gfortp:
    $(MAKE) $(EXEFILE) "FC=mpif90" "FCOPTS= -O3" "FCDEFS=$(FCDEFS)" \
    "FCDEBUG=" "CPP=" "CPPF=cpp" "CPPOPTS=-traditional-cpp" \
    "CPPDEFS=$(CPPDFLAGS)"
```

'debug'  :

```
# Linux gfortran debugging (GNU Fortran)
linux-gfort-g:
    $(MAKE) $(EXEFILE) "FC=gfortran" "FCOPTS=" "FCDEFS=$(FCDEFS)" \
    "FCDEBUG=-fbounds-check -Wall -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fimplicit-none - 
fbacktrace" \
        "CPP=" "CPPF=cpp" "CPPOPTS=-traditional-cpp" "CPPDEFS=$(CPPDFLAGS)"
```

Comment: You should show a complete [mre]. That links also contains suggestion how to isolate such an example from a larger code.

Comment: What do you mean by "arrays seems to be accessed outside of WHERE conditions" and what connection does that have with the floating point exception that's raised? If you want help tracking down an FPE we'll need to see a [mre].

Comment: Getting a floating point exception raised in a debug build which was asked to trap floating point exceptions seems about as far from "ironic" as I imagine one can get. From that and the title, it seems you may well be misinterpreting what problem you are experiencing. Work on the [mre] really will help ensure everyone can see the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get the floating-point exception only when your are compiling with debug options is this parameter:

```
-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow
```

When you add this to your normal compile options, the program will also fail in normal mode.

You will find more details about these debugging options in the documentation for [-ffpe-trap=*list*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html#index-ffpe-trap_003dlist). Make only one of the three active one by one to see which causes the exception. The documentation has examples:

- *invalid*: invalid floating point operation, such as `SQRT(-1.0)`
- *zero*: division by zero
- *overflow*: overflow in a floating point operation

Your code uses multiplication, so it is very possible it creates an **overflow**.

This minimal reproducible example fails with the same FPE exception when compiled with `-ffpe-trap=overflow`:

```
program fpe
    real :: a = 1000000000.0
    a = a ** a
end program fpe
```

Result:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.
```